# Lassen vs. Können

Tags: standard-german

Under what circumstances would it be acceptable/normal to replace “Können” with “Lassen”?

Example: “Das kann nachgebildet werden” and “Das läßt sich nachbilden.”

Comment: As you've demonstrated, this is possible only when *können* is used with a passive construction. "Ich kann singen" cannot be reformulated this way.

Answer (score 6):

Diese vier Varianten sind synonym:

> Das **kann** [Partizip] werden.
>   Das **lässt sich** [Verb].
>   Das **kann man** [Verb].
>   Das ist ...**bar**.

Beispiele:
gemacht - machen - machbar 
erlernt - erlernen - erlernbar 
gegessen - essen - essbar 
angewendet - anwenden - anwendbar
usw., wobei das *lässt sich* nicht immer 'rund' klingt, z.B. bei *essen*.